# Can someone explain this concept about exact differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

if I have $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$ with solution $F(x,y)=c$, then to check if they are exact then I need to check $M_y=N_x$ Why is it be incorrect to state that this is equivalent to   that $M_x=N_y$, and that this can also be used to check exactness. I can easily follow the steps to work out an answer but conceptually it is not 'clicking'.

Answer (score 1):

When we say that $Mdx+Ndy=0$ is exact, it means the left hand side is the total differential of a function $f(x,y)$, which means 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy.$$

In other words, there exists a function $f(x,y)$, such that $M=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, N=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. You see that from this, $M_y=N_x$ is definitely a necessary condition, because both of them are $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}$. But your condition is not true in general.

Comment: Ok it is starting to make sense. I was confused because I know later we integrate $M$ with respect to $x$ and $N$ with respect to $y$.

Comment: @anna_xox: That is because $M$ is supposed to be already a partial derivative with respect to $x$, namely, $M=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. So to recover $f$ from $M$, you integrate with respect to $x$.

Comment: @KittyL Why we say that the necessary and suficient condition for a differential $df=Mdx + Ndy$ to be exact is to check the mixed derivatives $M_y$ and $N_x$? I understand that if they are not equal then the differential is not exact but why if they are equal the differential is exact? How do we prove that being equal is necessary and sufficient condition? What if a differential is not exact and still have $M_y=N_x$? We must prove that that is ALWAYS true that $M_y \neq N_x$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user599310: There is the condition for that. $M$ and $N$ must be continuous and their first partial derivatives must be continuous in a simple region $D$. You can find the proof in any typical differential equation textbook. The proof is also related to the concept of path independence and conservative field. You may look up a multi-variable calculus textbook for the details.